# multiple counts in single mysql query

Tags: mysql

How can I do multiple counts for the same field in mysql? The code below for a single count works fine

```
SELECT fruit, COUNT(DISTINCT site) AS `apple` FROM grocery where fruit like '%06201%'
```

However, when I have tried this but I get syntax error

```
SELECT
    SUM(fruit like '%06201%') AS `apple`,
    SUM(fruit like '%02206%') AS `pears`,
FROM grocery
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    SUM(fruit like '%06201%') AS `apple`,
    SUM(fruit like '%02206%') AS `pears`,
                                        ^
                                        here
FROM grocery
```

You have two commata, but you only need one.

Comment: Ah that work, thanks. I was sure I was doing something silly :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove extra comma before `FROM`

```
SELECT
    SUM(fruit like '%06201%') AS `apple`,
    SUM(fruit like '%02206%') AS `pears`
FROM grocery
```